# Jobs and the Careers pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Can you add a link, or otherwise merge the functionality of the jobs.SO/Su/SF.com site with the careers page please?

In particular, I find myself wanting to search jobs from the careers section. Its possible that there are multiple points of integration between the two.

Answer (score 3):

This is planned.

Comment: Mr. Spolsky Lives!